# Tratando null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

Estou recebendo, no meu back end, um objeto json da tela dessa forma:

```
{
    "pessoa": {
        "nome": "aa",
        "nomeSocial": "aa",
        "tipoPessoa": "F",
        "nomePai":"",
        "dataNascimento": "15/06/1983",
        "nomeMae": "a"
    },
    "cns": "aa",

    "pessoasEnderecos": {
        "cep": "a", 
        "nomeLogradouro": "a",
        "nomeBairro": "a"
    }
}
```

A questão é que estou tendo um nullPointerException porque, por óbvio, o meu json `nomePai` está vazio, como eu faço para tratar esse erro e persistir os dados no banco passando o nomePai null, já que não é obrigatório pela regra de negócio?

Existem vários atributos que se enquadram nessa regra, coloquei apenas um para demonstração.

Meu método:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/pacientes")
    public HttpStatus cadastrarPacientes(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) throws ParseException  {

        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            entidades.setIdEntidade(json.get("pessoa").get("entidade").get("idEntidade").asLong());

            Pessoas pessoas = new Pessoas();
            pessoas.setNome(json.get("pessoa").get("nome").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeSocial(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeSocial").textValue());

            pessoas.setNomePai(json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeMae(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeMae").textValue());
            pessoas.setDataNascimento(formato.parse(json.get("pessoa").get("dataNascimento").textValue()));

            pessoas.setTipoPessoa(json.get("pessoa").get("tipoPessoa").textValue());
}
```

Comment: `pessoas.setNomePai(json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai") == null ? 
 null : json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai").textValue());`

Comment: @Articuno funcionou !! Posta seu comentário como resposta. Obrigado !

Comment: @Articuno Funcionou somente para os valores em String.. no caso, por exemplo;; `entidades.setIdEntidade(json.get("pessoa").get("entidade").get("idEntidade").asLong());` continua dando erro..

Comment: Ai tem que ler a documentação do método `asLong` e ver que tipo de retorno ele dá quando nada é retornado. Eu não sei que api você está utilizando, então, nem tem como sugerir algo. Da uma olhada na documentação deste método e qualquer coisa, posta o link da doc aqui se ficar em duvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma resolução simples seria utilizar operação ternária para evitar a tentativa de acesso a um retorno nulo:

```
pessoas.setNomePai(json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai") == null ? null : json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai").textValue());
```

Dessa forma, mantem-se o retorno nulo caso o valor retornado seja vazio, mas o `textValue()` só irá ser chamado caso não seja nulo.